# How to provision react app and node js on aws ec2 using terraform -automated?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

How to automatically deploy Ec2 instance programmaticaly?

I have a website, abc.com and our website is like a tournament registration portal and any user landing to our website can make payment and request for a similar portal under the requested site URI, let's say xyz.com.

So once the admin receives the portal request, if he accepts the request, a new EC2 instance would be created for the request site URI, xyz.com. And that site would be a clone of our website with frontend and backend in that instance created.

I have my react js front end and node js as my backend with MySQL ,I was advised to use terraform , but I couldn't find a proper documentation/blog to do the above operation with ec2 instance instead I see only with s3 instance.

so please guide me with a proper way to deploy react js and node js in ec2 instance using terraform ?

Note: I want this to be an automated process from a request from front end. (for eg: When the admin decides to accept a request for provisioning on front end react app, it should create an instance automatically )

Comment: This question is too vague, and shows no effort on your part... what you are trying to do and describe in the note is quite complex and time-consuming to implement, if you don't want to put the time to research yourself hire someone to do it for you.

Comment: I am sorry, I am totally a beginner in this part, I am doing as an intern work, I have done 60 days of hard work day and night with front end and backend, I am stuck at this cloud provisioning, so please help me out

Comment: StackOverflow is for precise questions...  if you are stuck at cloud provisioning, show the code of what you have, and what errors are you getting

Comment: the problem is I couldn't find a path to start and I thought people here were really in showing the path at least . A single link of documentation of blog to deploy react and node js would be more than enough fo rme to workout and go to the trail and error phase

Comment: I have already created an EC2 instance and deployed my react and node js with nginx configured , But i want to do cloud provisioning using terraform , the link which you sent was just to create a ec2 instance .

Comment: Show the terraform code of what have you tried... you say already created an EC2 instance and deployed my react and node js, where is the code for that? was it done manually? What terraform resources have you used?

Comment: I have created an ec2 instance manually and deployed manually react and node , everything normally . just like every other instance , I haven't tried terraform , because I can't a proper tutorial to do so.

Comment: You have to do some research by yourself, google is a great starting point `intro to terraform` first link is:
https://www.terraform.io/intro/index.html